# How to read in .csv data, then create a subset of that data based on conditional filtering?

Tags: r

I'm new to R programming, although I have been programming a number of other languages for years. I'm having a hard time finding any relevant information on this simple problem through searching the R documentation and stack overflow etc., so some help would be very much appreciated.

Here's the problem:
After reading in data from a .csv, I need to create a new dataset that contains only those observations where the "value" field is between 0 and 100 inclusive (there are 4 fields and ~2500 rows of data). I have no problem reading in the data and displaying it. My problem is when I try to take the list of input data and filter it based on the range condition for the "value" column.

Here's my input:

```
   #read in the data from the sensor file
    data = read.csv("C:/Code/sensor.txt", header=TRUE)
    for (i in seq(4, nrow(data), 4)) {
      if (as.integer(data[i])>0) {
        print(data[i])
      }
    }
```

I am getting the error output:

```
> for (i in seq(4, nrow(data), 4)) {
+   if (as.integer(data[i])>0) {
+     print(data[i])
+   }
+ }
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

EDIT:

Here is some sample data:

timestamp, siteid, sensorid, value
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,1,1,24
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,1,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,1,3,60
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,2,1,0
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,2,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,2,3,100
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,3,1,36
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,3,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,3,3,38
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,4,1,99
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,4,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 PST 2016,4,3,84
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,1,1,#ERROR#
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,1,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,1,3,96
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,2,1,28
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,2,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,2,3,94
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,3,1,3
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,3,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,3,3,95
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,4,1,72
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,4,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:15:00 PST 2016,4,3,21
Thu Jan 07 00:30:00 PST 2016,1,1,160
Thu Jan 07 00:30:00 PST 2016,1,2,5
Thu Jan 07 00:30:00 PST 2016,1,3,34

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always try to give us some reproductible example of data

```
data.beetween0and100 <- data[data$column.with.values => 0 & data$column.with.values <=100,]
```

This how you get data with desired values. Also you data frames how to dimmension rows, and columns so data[i] is bad but, data[i,] is a i-row of data frame.

```
print(data[i,]) #will work
```

## with you data

#read in the data from the sensor file

```
    data = read.csv("C:/Code/sensor.txt", header=TRUE)
    for (i in seq(4, nrow(data), 4)) {
      if (as.integer(data[i,numberofvaluecolumn])>0) {
        print(data[i,numberofvaluecolumn])
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's great, I've got it working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the answer satisfy you, please give me arrow up.

Answer (score 0):

If the function as.integer is throwing an error then perhaps read.csv() hasn't read  the values in a format which as.integer() can handle.

Use str(data) or head() and tail() to see what read.csv() is producing.#

Looking at your your example data, adding the argument

```
na.strings = "#ERROR#"
```

to read.csv() might solve the issue.

Comment: Your str(data) tip pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, loops in R are usually pretty slow and should be used with caution.  With a dataset of only 2,500 records it probably isn't an issue, but worth mentioning if you are going to start using larger datasets.

If you are going to be doing a lot of data manipulation I would recommend becoming familiar with the dplyr library, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf.  It makes data manipulation very quick and easy.

```
data<-data %>%
    filter(values>0,values<100)
```